# How to read complete document from cosmos db without mapping to a model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to read documents from cosmos DB collection which have no pre-defined schema so reading them as dynamic object or JObject(tried both of them), ReadItemAsync function working correctly and returning object as expected but when this object returned to the client as the response of HTTP request all the properties of the document somehow get assigned with an empty array i.e.([]). Why is this happening?

```
     public async Task<JObject> GetItemAsync(string id, string partitionKey)
        {
                var result = await _container.ReadItemAsync<JObject>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
                return result.Resource;            
        }
```

[image]

**Expected response**

```
{
    "id": "z_km_pm_clinic_WA1200-6-60076_1610430115000",
    "yearmonth": "202101",
    "asset_id": "WA1200-6-60076",
    "bucket_starttime": "1610430115000",
    "bucket_endtime": "0",
    "buckettype_visibility": "1",
    "wl_engn1_spd_rpm_high_idle_p_mode": "1807.0",
    "wl_engn1_spd_rpm_low_idle_p_mode": "NULL",
    "wl_engn1_spd_rpm_test_2": "NULL",
    "wl_engn1_spd_rpm_test_3": "NULL",
    "wl_engn1_spd_rpm_new_metric_test": "NULL",
    "release_version": "NULL",
    "test_version": "NULL",
    "version": "NULL",
    "_rid": "1G*************AAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs******************AAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0000990b-0000-1b00-0000-********000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1622013082
}
```

**Actual response**

```
{"id":[],"yearmonth":[],"asset_id":[],"bucket_starttime":[],"bucket_endtime":[],"buckettype_visibility":[],"wl_engn1_spd_rpm_high_idle_p_mode":[],"wl_engn1_spd_rpm_low_idle_p_mode":[],"wl_engn1_spd_rpm_test_2":[],"wl_engn1_spd_rpm_test_3":[],"wl_engn1_spd_rpm_new_metric_test":[],"release_version":[],"test_version":[],"version":[],"_rid":[],"_self":[],"_etag":[],"_attachments":[],"_ts":[]}
```

Comment: The parameters in the request is not being found in the database and server is returning empty data.  Common reasons for issue 1) You are querying the wrong server or wrong database 2) The type of variable in the request does not match type in database.  Your request could be a string while the database is storing value as an integer.

Comment: database server is responding as expected you can see the snapshot of debug window, for point 2, I'm not mapping(and I don't want to) my document from database to a model. @jdweng

Comment: That is not what is in the response that the client is seeing.  Why is server sending an empty response?